# How to target a specific object with Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a class called Features in my models.py. In my html, I am displaying a list on the right that excludes two of these Features, one is the active feature that has been selected, the other is the most recently added since they are the main content of my page. The remaining Features in the list are displayed by date and do show what I am expecting. 
Now, I want to single out the first, second and third Features (title only) in THAT list so I can place them in their own separate divs - because each has unique css styling. There are probably numerous ways of doing this, but I can't seem to figure any of them out.

[This is a link](http://davidalanherron.pythonanywhere.com/#) to my project to give a better idea of what I want (basically trying to get the content in those colored boxes on the right.)

I'm just learning Django (and Python really), so thanks for your patience and help!

HTML

```
       {% for f in past_features %}
            {% if f.title != selected_feature.title %}
            {% if f.title != latest_feature.title %}
                <h1>{{ f.title }}</h1>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

VIEWS

```
def feature_detail(request, pk):
    selected_feature = get_object_or_404(Feature, pk=pk)
    latest_feature = Feature.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
    past_features = Feature.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    test = Feature.objects.last()
    context = {'selected_feature': selected_feature,
               'latest_feature': latest_feature,
               'past_features': past_features,
               'test': test}
    return render(request, 'gp/feature_detail.html', context)
```

MODELS

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100, default='')
    content = models.TextField(default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def __iter__(self):
        return [
            self.id,
            self.title ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either store the first three Features in separate variables in your context or add checks to your template loop like `{% if forloop.first %}` or `{% if forloop.counter == 2 %}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to not have the

```
  selected_feature
  latest_feature
```

these two records out of the past_features queryset, then you can use [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) on the past_features query and pass the id's of the selected_features and latest_feature objects.

The views.py would look like:

```
 def feature_detail(request, pk):
    selected_feature = get_object_or_404(Feature, pk=pk)
    latest_feature = Feature.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
    # Collect all the id's present in the latest_feature

    excluded_ids = [record.pk for record in latest_feature]
    excluded_ids.append(selected_feature.pk)

    #This would only return the objects excluding the id present in the list
    past_features = Feature.objects.order_by('-pub_date').exclude(id__in=excluded_ids)
    test = Feature.objects.last()
    context = {'selected_feature': selected_feature,
               'latest_feature': latest_feature,
               'past_features': past_features,
               'test': test}
 return render(request, 'gp/feature_detail.html', context)
```

Django provides a rich ORM and well documented, go through the [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/) options for further information.

Comment: Thanks kt14. This was also very helpful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For access to a specific object in Django templates see following example:

For access to first object you can use `{{ students.0 }}`

For access to second object you can use `{{ students.1 }}`

For access to a specific field for example firstname in object 4 you can use `{{ students.3.firstname }}`

For access to image field in second object you can use `{{ students.1.photo.url }}`

For access to id in first object you can use `{{ students.0.id }}`